# abstracting over type constructors

Tags: scala, generics, types, abstraction, type-parameter

I have the following toy function:

```
def test[T](x: Option[List[Option[T]]])
{
    for (a <- x; b <- a; c <- b) println(c)
    println("----------")
}
```

How can I generalize the above function so it also works with `Option[Option[Option[T]]]` or `List[List[List[T]]]` or any other combination of `Option` and `List`?

The following attempt obviously doesn't work, because types aren't type constructors:

```
def test2[Q,R,S,T](x: Q[R[S[T]]])
```

In C++, I would probably use template templates for this purpose. Does Scala have something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you use [Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/)? If so this is pretty easy with the [`Each`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Each.scala) type class:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def test[Q[_]: Each, R[_]: Each, S[_]: Each, T](x: Q[R[S[T]]]) {
  for (a <- x; b <- a; c <- b) println(c)
  println("----------")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Option and List each implements the foreach-method used by the for-loop, but does not have have a common super-type for it. However structural types makes it possible by declaring the method that we want as a type.

```
type E[V] = {def foreach[U](f: (V) => U)}
def test2[Q[R] <: E[R],R[S] <: E[S],S[T] <: E[T],T](x: Q[R[S[T]]]) {
  for (a <- x; b <- a; c <- b) println(c)
  println("----------")
}
```

Examples:

```
scala> test2(List(List(List(8))))
8

scala> test2(Some(List(Some(8))))
8
```

If you change the for-loop to use yield you need to change E to implement flatmap and map-methods instead of foreach.

Comment: It works if we generalise to Option: 'val n: Option[Nothing] = None; test2(Some(List(n)))'. I'm not sure why that is.